# Create temp row for each row in existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have two tables. In the one table I have a list of dorm rooms with maximum occupancy like so:

```
dorm_building | dorm_room | max_occupancy
```

Then I have a list of students and the room they are assigned to like this:

```
people_id | people_name | dorm_building | dorm_room
```

I want to create a table that has a row for each potential occupant (e.g. if a room has five possible occupants, there should be five rows for this table). Then I want to join the student records to this table. I'll then spit this out using Reporting Services to provide a visual map of who is in what room and where empty spots are still available.

Help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
With Numbers As
    (
    Select Row_Number() Over ( Order By C1.object_id ) As Value
    From sys.syscolumns As C1
        Cross Join sys.syscolumns As C2
    )
    , NumberedStudents As
    (
    Select people_id, people_name, dorm_building, dorm_room
        , Row_Number() Over ( Partition By dorm_building, dorm_room Order By people_id ) As OccupantNum
    From Students
    )
Select ...
From DormRooms
    Join Numbers
        On N.Value <= DormRooms.max_occupancy
    Left Join NumberedStudents
        On NumberedStudents.dorm_building = DormRooms.dorm_building
            And NumberedStudents.dorm_room = DormRooms.dorm_room
            And NumberedStudents.OccupantNum= Numbers
```

I'm using two features in this solution which are available in SQL Server 2005 and beyond. The first is common-table expression or CTE for short and the second is a ranking function (in this case Row_Number). The common-table expressions are the `Numbers` table and the `NumberedStudents` table. Think of these as saved views or queries. The `Numbers` CTE creates a sequential list of numbers by cross joining any two tables (I chose sys.syscolumns). That enables me to generate the "placeholder" rows you requested. The Row_Number function simply creates a sequential list of numbers for every row returned.

In the NumberedStudents CTE, I am also using the `Partition By` feature with the Row_Number function which restarts the numbering of occupants for each dorm_building and dorm_room. This will effectively give a sequential number to each student in the room.

Comment: Thanks. This should work. I'm wondering though, could I do something like this (pseudo):
For Each row in (select * from dorms)
  i = 0
  if i <= row.maximum_occupants then
    insert into #temp row.dorm_name, i
  end if
Next

Comment: @davemackey - In general, you only want to resort to an iterative solution in SQL if you absolutely must and that should only happen if there is no set-based solution. In this case, I think you do have a set-based solution and so I would go with that first.

Answer (score 2):

Do you actually **need** the temporary table? Why not just write a fairly simple query, something like:

```
select dr.dorm_building, dr.dorm_room, dr.max_occupancy, ra.people_id, ra.people_name
from dorm_room_table dr left join room_assignment_table ra 
on dr.dorm_building = ra.dorm_building and dr.dorm_room = ra.dorm_room
```

then use a table, grouped by dorm_room and dorm_building, with the details rows to report occupancy and a group footing to report vacant places (Fields!max_occupancy.value - CountRows()).